# Meteor error handling for template naming typo errors

Tags: javascript, meteor, error-handling

Recently I had an error with a name being used in a helpers file. Because the template name being used was not valid, all my global helpers stopped working (Template.registerHelper()). In the past I have faced similar circumstances where one naming error causes my entire web app to crash.

Is there a way to handle error so that it does not affect other JS files?

The error just is from naming issues and is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined.

Basically i'm asking how can I prevent my WHOLE app from breaking when one js file is erroring.

Comment: Can you add some code to demonstrate?

Comment: The error just is from naming issues and is

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this very same question on the meteor forums. The response was that **the feature is not available yet and it is bad practice** anyway to leave your application in a state where it runs with errors.

https://forums.meteor.com/t/entire-app-breaks-when-one-file-errors/19431